# React useAuth need to reconnect if page refresh

Tags: reactjs, authentication, supabase

I created an app with react, supabase and useAuth. All is working well except when I refresh the page.
I need to reconnect every time I refresh the page even if the user is still logged in.
I can see in the log that I still have a user and token but the information isn't transmitted to the page to re-render

Here is the components

App

```
import './App.css';
import Sidenav from "./components/Sidenav";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from './context/AuthProvider';

function App() {

  const {user} = useAuth();

  console.log("Loading the app page...")

  if(user){
    console.log("User is logged")

    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className='' style={{marginTop: "56px"}}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-auto">
              <Sidenav />
            </div>
            <div className="col">
              <div className='mt-5'>
                <Outlet/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    ) 

  } else {

    console.log("No current session")

    return (<Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />)

  }
}

export default App;
```

Auth provider

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import supabase from "../server/Supabase";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

const signOut = () => supabase.auth.signOut();
const login = (email, password) => supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({ email, password });

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    // Get the session information for when a user refresh the page
    supabase.auth.getSession().then(({ data: { session } }) => {

      let state = session?.user ? "User found" : "No user"
      console.log("GET SESSION...")
      console.log(state)
      setUser(session?.user);

    })

    // Get the refresh token while connected to avoid to be disconnected between each pages
    const { data } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
      
      if (event === "SIGNED_OUT") {
        
        console.log("Authentication state change - SIGNED OUT")

        setUser(null);

      } else {

        console.log("Authentication state change - " + event)
        console.log("Session user ", session?.user)
        setUser(session?.user);
      }
        
    });

    return () => {
      data.subscription.unsubscribe();
    };

  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, signOut }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

index

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import ErrorPage from './pages/Error-404';
import Calendar from "./pages/Calendar";
import Timesheet from "./pages/Timesheet";
import Account from "./pages/Account";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import Project from "./pages/Project";
import Report from "./pages/Report";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import SignUp from "./pages/SignUp";
import Task from './pages/Task';
// import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import AuthProvider from './context/AuthProvider';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: "Calendar",
        element: <Calendar />,
      },
      {
        path: "Timesheet",
        element: <Timesheet />,
      },
      {
        path: "Report",
        element: <Report />,
      },
      {
        path: "Project",
        element: <Project />,
      },
      {
        path: "Task",
        element: <Task />,
      },
      {
        path: "Task/:id",
        element: <Task />,
      },
      {
        path: "Settings",
        element: <Settings />,
      },
      {
        path: "Account",
        element: <Account />,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "Login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: "SignUp",
    element: <SignUp />,
  },
  
]);


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/> 
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more:
// reportWebVitals();
```

The logs while refreshing the page

```
GET SESSION...
AuthProvider.jsx:21 User found
AuthProvider.jsx:37 Authentication state change - INITIAL_SESSION
AuthProvider.jsx:38 Session user  {id: …}
AuthProvider.jsx:20 GET SESSION...
AuthProvider.jsx:21 User found
```

The logs while connecting

```
Authentication state change - SIGNED_IN
AuthProvider.jsx:38 Session user  {id: …}
Login.jsx:30 {user: {…}, session: {…}, error: null}
Login.jsx:35 User and session ok
App.jsx:11 Loading the app page...
App.jsx:14 User is logged
App.jsx:11 Loading the app page...
App.jsx:14 User is logged
```